# When a thread that calls SetWaitableTimer exits while another thread is waiting on the timer, is the timer cancelled?

Tags: windows, winapi

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

According to msdn, in the remarks sections, it states:
"If the thread that set the timer terminates and there is an associated completion routine, the timer is canceled. However, the state of the timer remains unchanged. **If there is no completion routine, then terminating the thread has no effect on the timer.**"

Then further down, it states:
"**If the thread that called SetWaitableTimer exits, the timer is canceled. This stops the timer before it can be set to the signaled state and cancels outstanding APCs; it does not change the signaled state of the timer.**"

Hence my question, 
if I have one thread calling SetWaitableTimer without an associated completion routine and another thread calling WaitOnMultipleObjects(passing in the timer object handle) and the thread that calls SetWaitiableTmer exits shortly thereafter, would the timer object be cancelled or would it still become signaled when the period expires?

Answer (score 4):

To give more information directly from the implementation of waitable timers: if you use a CompletionRoutine, the timer is placed on a linked list chained off the thread which called SetWaitableTimer.  When the thread is terminated, the kernel walks the dying thread's linked list and cancels are timers which are still queued.

If you're not using a completion routine, the timer is never added to any thread's linked list and thus isn't cancelled when any particular thread dies.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is somewhat unclear. I think the best you can do is test it yourself. I believe however that the timer cancels automatically only if the I/O completion routine is used.

I can give some "theoretical" background about windows APCs, to justify my (educated) guess.

APC = "asynchronous procedure call". In windows every user-mode thread is equipped with a so-called APC queue, a system-managed queue of procedures that must be called on this thread. A thread may enter a so-called "alertable wait" state (on purpose), during which it may execute one or more of the procedures in this queue. You may either put the procedure call in the APC queue manually, or issue an I/O, which on completion will "put" the procedure call there.

In simple words the scenario is the following: you issue several I/Os, and then you wait for either of them to complete (or fail), and, perhaps, some other events. You then call one of the alertable-waiting functions: `SleepEx`, `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` or similar.

Important note: this mechanism is designed to support a **single-threaded** concurrency. That is, the same thread issues several I/Os, waits for something to happen, and responds appropriately. All the APC routines are **guaranteed** to be called in the **same thread**. Hence - if this thread exits - there's no way to call them. Hence - all the outstanding I/Os are also **cancelled**.

There are several Windows API functions that deal with asynchronous I/O, whereas they allow a choice of several completion mechanisms (such as `ReadFileEx`): APC, setting an event, or putting a completion in the I/O completion port. If those functions are used with APC - they automatically cancel the I/O if the issuing thread exits.

Hence, I guess that waitable timer auto-cancels only if used with APC.